# What is lpformnum attribute?

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome

I'm making simple html+css page and added there form without any attributes (id or class). When i view it in chrome dev tools, it shows `<form lpformnum="1">` instead of just `<form>`. Just curious about what is `lpformnum` and why it's added :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I am fairly positive that it comes from the LastPass browser extension. This allows LastPass to identify the form and to autofill it.